# Stretch one column, shrink others in Android TableLayot

Tags: android, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

Below I would like to strech the `pool_team` column and have the others shrink to the column width.  I can't seem to get it right though.   The other columns will contain an integer of small size and the `pool_team` will contain a long name that may wrap.

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pool_table"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/pool_row"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_number"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_team"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_wins"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_loses"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_point_difference"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pool_place"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Comment: can you post an image what it looks like and what you would look like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/pool_table"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/pool_row"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_team"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Some longer text that may or may not wrap around to the next line...." />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_wins"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_loses"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_point_difference"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pool_place"
        android:layout_weight=".1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="123" />
</TableRow>
```